# Cannot push images to the docker-registry using the kubectl plugin

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-registry, centos8

I'm a fresher when it comes to using k8s. Please help me with the issue I am facing. I am trying to push the images to the local docker-registry. Some of the images are being pushed successfully, but in a couple of seconds it is failing. It is giving me this error message:

```
{"status":"The push refers to repository [docker-registry:30001/netapp/astracc/22.08.1-26/graphql-server]"}
{"errorDetail":{"message":"Get "https://docker-registry:30001/v2/\": dial tcp 192.168.0.96:30001: connect: connection refused"},"error":"Get "https://docker-registry:30001/v2/\": dial tcp 192.168.0.96:30001: connect: connection refused"}
```

I tried checking if my docker-registry is running. This is the output to check if my registry is up and running:

```
[root@kubmas2 acc]# docker ps | grep registry

ab05d3e41abf registry "/entrypoint.sh /etc…" About a minute ago Up About a minute k8s_registry_docker-registry-547576f64c-9w8rl_registry_b48428e8-4b45-422f-906c-37c6c6286f80_0

d59cab9271fc k8s.gcr.io/pause:3.6 "/pause" About a minute ago Up About a minute k8s_POD_docker-registry-547576f64c-9w8rl_registry_b48428e8-4b45-422f-906c-37c6c6286f80_0

f40fdeae0b7c registry.k8s.io/sig-storage/csi-node-driver-registrar "/csi-node-driver-re…" 8 days ago Up 8 days k8s_driver-registrar_trident-csi-nxhxb_trident_6245b9f7-205a-463a-bb7b-0d15a08b5189_0
```